# Манипуляции с БД(sqlite, mysql) через C++

Tags: c++, mysql, sql

Пытаюсь найти способ для создания/редактирования/удаления БД(sqlite, mysql) из кода программы на C++. В данный момент хочу найти способ для использования в QT(читал где-то, что он предоставляет возможности какие-то для работы с БД), но интересуют также универсальные для C++ варианты. Честно говоря, уже перерыл весь Google/Yandex в поисках. Нашел пару вариантов, но не могу разобраться/получаются ошибки.
Вот список того, с чем пытался разобраться:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424828/how-to-connect-mysql-database-using-c
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58187088/how-to-add-connector-c-and-boost-to-clion-project-on-windows-10

Понял, что для моих задач нужны т.н. Boost и C++ Connector.

C++ Connector установил по пути, который указан в CMakeLists.txt. Boost в корне диска C. Их нужно добавлять в PATH?

Код CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(Test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR "C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0")

# You only really need to include your source files here.
add_executable(shared-editor-server
        main.cpp
        #connectDB.cpp
        #server.cpp
        )

# Add the MySQL include directories to this target.
target_include_directories(shared-editor-server PRIVATE
        ${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/include/jdbc
        )
target_include_directories(shared-editor-server PRIVATE
        ${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/include/jdbc/cppconn
        )

# Link the MySQL library to your executable.
target_link_libraries(shared-editor-server PRIVATE
        ${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/lib64/vs14/mysqlcppconn8.lib
        )

add_executable(Test main.cpp)
```

Код main.cpp:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

/*
  Include directly the different
  headers from cppconn/ and mysql_driver.h + mysql_util.h
  (and mysql_connection.h). This will reduce your build time!
*/
#include "mysql_connection.h"

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Running 'SELECT 'Hello World!' »AS _message'..." << endl;

    try {
        sql::Driver *driver;
        sql::Connection *con;
        sql::Statement *stmt;
        sql::ResultSet *res;

        /* Create a connection */
        driver = get_driver_instance();
        con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");
        /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
        con->setSchema("test");

        stmt = con->createStatement();
        res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message"); // replace with your statement
        while (res->next()) {
            cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
            /* Access column data by alias or column name */
            cout << res->getString("_message") << endl;
            cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
            /* Access column fata by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
            cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
        }
        delete res;
        delete stmt;
        delete con;

    } catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
        cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
        cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line "  << __LINE__ << endl;
        cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
        cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
        cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Код в main.cpp взял с какого-то ресурса по этим ссылкам в ответах, хотел с ним начать разбираться, но застрял на подключении заголовочных файлов коннектора(или boost, или 2 в 1). Еще читал, что папку boost надо скопировать в папку include внутри папки с коннектором, но такой папки у меня нет. Ее создать нужно?

У кого какие мысли?

UPD: По работе в рамках QT подсказали. Может кто-нибудь знает насчет проблемы при работе в рамках чистого C++?

Comment: http://katecpp.github.io/sqlite-with-qt/ https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.10/qtsql-index.html https://stackoverflow.com/q/1429782/13970074 и так далее

Comment: *По работе в рамках QT подсказали. Может кто-нибудь знает насчет проблемы при работе в рамках чистого C++?* - что значит в рамках чистого C++? В стандартной библиотеке нет методов для работы с базами данных, если вы об этом

Comment: @dIm0n Под рамками чистого C++ я понимаю возможность подключения БД к "не QT-программе". С тем, что вы скинули я понял что к чему, но работать оно будет лишь при разработке в среде QT Creator(что мне и нужно в данный момент). А вот перенести такой проект с qmake на cmake будет чуть более, чем ужасно(но можно, я видел способы для этого). Короче говоря, сейчас я привязан к QT Creator, а мне интересно, есть ли еще несложные способы подключения БД(даже со сторонними либами) в рамках работы в CLion, Eclipse и т.д.

Comment: Пажждите, Qt никак не связан с IDE Qt Creator, вы можете использовать фреймворк Qt в любом приложении и любой IDE, в `CMake`, например, подключение занимает пару строк https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-qt.7.html. Если вам просто не хочется использовать Qt по каким-то причинам, то существует куча других библиотек для работы с БД: https://github.com/SRombauts/SQLiteCpp, https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-cpp и так далее

Comment: @dIm0n Я понимаю, что есть способы работать с Qt под другими IDE, но меня интересует именно отдельная работа от Qt в целом. Вот насчет второй ссылки, что вы сейчас привели, я и спрашиваю в своем вопросе. Мне не удается использовать C++ Connector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у меня есть пара идей для разрешения Вашей ситуации.

1. Для контроля пакетов библиотек и избавления себя от мук с Cmake попробуйте vcpkg - отличный инструмент, универсальный и кросплатворменный. Там есть куча библиотек, в том числе и для лаботы с БД, boost итп (реально очень много). Ставите, `vcpkg search sql`, `vcpkg install <library>`,

В CMake

```
find_package(<library>)
...
target_link_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ... <library>)
```

, где  вам подскажет сам vcpkg

Только не забудьте указать -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE для CMake. Собственно, подробнее смотрите [здесь](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg)

2. Могу подсказать альтернативу Qt, которую можно линковать в статик бесплатно, хотя по функциональности и интерфейсам она в некотором роде даже лучше.
   Вот, смотрите: https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Data.SQLite.html